Use Swift `#Observable` with Objective-C model
I'm trying to use an Objective-C model via a SwiftUI code. This is a simple demo I made:
@protocol CarProtocol <NSObject>
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString * color;
- (void)changeColor;
@end

@protocol PersonProtocol <NSObject>
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString * name;
- (void)changeName;
@end

@interface Car : NSObject <CarProtocol>

@property (strong, readwrite) NSString * color;

- (instancetype)initWithColor:(NSString *)color;
- (void)changeColor;

@end


@implementation Car

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.color = @"";
    }
    return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithColor:(NSString *)color {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.color = color;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)changeColor {
    NSArray *colors = @[@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green", @"Yellow", @"Black", @"White"];
    NSString *newColor = self.color;
    
    while (self.color == nil || [newColor isEqualToString:self.color]) {
        newColor = colors[arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)colors.count)];
    }
    
    self.color = newColor;
    NSLog(@"The car color has been changed to %@", self.color);
}

@end

Then, I'm trying to access the Car object via the CarProtocol from Objective-C. My goal is to be able to modify the Car instance properties from both Swift (say, from a Text Field) and from the ObjC code (say, by calling car.changeColor()).
I've tried the following:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

extension Car: ObservableObject {
    public var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        publisher(for: \.color, options: .prior)
            .map { _ in }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    public static func randomCar() -> Car {
        let colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange"]
        return Car(color: colors.randomElement() ?? "Red")
    }
}


@Observable
class ObservableCar<CarT>
    where CarT: CarProtocol {
    public var car: CarT
    
    public init(_ car: CarT) {
        self.car = car
    }
}

struct SwiftObservableView<CarT>: View
    where CarT: CarProtocol & ObservableObject {
    @State var car: ObservableCar<CarT>
    
    public init(car: CarT) {
        self.car = ObservableCar(car)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Modification Form")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Color", text: $car.car.color)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Results")) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack() {
                            Text("Color")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(car.car.color)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Actions")) {
                    Button("Random Car") {
                        self.car = ObservableCar<CarT>(Car.randomCar() as! CarT)
                    }
                    Button("Assign from Objective-C") {
                        self.car.car.changeColor()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Car Data (Swift)")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftObservableView(car: Car(color: "Green"))
}

I can see swift modifications reflects, but not the call to changeColor. Do you have an idea on how to achieve the desired behavior using the new #Observable macros introduced in WWDC23? I could achieve it with plain Combine, without the usage of protocols. However, as my code is protocol oriented, I need to rely on protocols.

Edit: I've added here the way that I was able to achieve it using Combine
import SwiftUI
import Combine

extension PersonCombine: ObservableObject {
    public var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        publisher(for: \.name, options: .prior)
            .map { _ in }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension CarCombine: ObservableObject {
    public var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge3(
              owner.objectWillChange,
              publisher(for: \.owner, options: .prior).map { _ in },
              publisher(for: \.color, options: .prior).map { _ in }
          )
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    public static func randomCar() -> CarCombine {
        let colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange"]
        return CarCombine(color: colors.randomElement() ?? "Red")
    }
}

struct CombineView: View {
    @StateObject var car: CarCombine
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Modification Form")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Color", text: $car.color)
                    }
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Owner Name", text: $car.owner.name)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Results")) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Color")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(car.color)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Owner")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(car.owner.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Actions")) {
                    Button("Random Car") {
                        let randomCar = CarCombine.randomCar()
                        car.color = randomCar.color
                    }
                    Button("Assign Car.Color from Objective-C") {
                        car.changeColor()
                    }
                    Button("Assign Person.Name from Objective-C") {
                        car.owner.changeName()
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Owner Details")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailCombineView(person: car.owner)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Owner")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(car.owner.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Car Data (Combine)")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CombineView(car: CarCombine())
}


What's the point of ObservableCar? Why not just use Car directly?

Tried to use it as a view model, as in the future I'd like to have a ViewModel with few published properties.

That's a bad idea. SwiftUI Views are already view models. Just write whatever "published properties" you want in your view directly, as @States.

By the way, how did you "achieve it with plain Combine"?

Must you use an instance of Car? Can you subclass it and use that instead?

@Sweeper My situation was simplified here. Originally, I have a 1) parent framework that provides interfaces. This framework also have an Objective-C layer that consumes these interfaces for some business logic; 2) A client layer that implement the interfaces in (1) (as macOS and iOS behaves bit differently); 3) A UI layer that should somehow get work with the interfaces, agnostic to the platform (as we use SwiftUI), extend them with Observables; 4) The actual app (iOS/macOS) which instantiate the correct platform interface and send it to the UI.

@Sweeper I've updated the question to list how I was able to achieve it using Combine.

Okay, why couldn't the same approach be used with protocols? Instead of @Observable, you can still create an ObservableObject that wraps something conforming to CarProtocol, and merge the publishers as you do here.

@Sweeper I'm just worried that Combine will be deprecated soon due to the introduction of Observables, and then my code won't work anymore.

Don’t worry. @Observable is never meant as a replacement for ObservableObject.

By extending the Car class to conform to ObservableObject, we can update the car's color from both SwiftUI and Objective-C. The UI automatically reflects changes using Combine’s objectWillChange, keeping everything in sync.
import SwiftUI
import Combine

extension Car: ObservableObject {
    public var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher {
        let willChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
        let originalChangeColor = self.changeColor
        self.changeColor = {
            willChange.send()
            originalChangeColor()
        }
        return willChange
    }
    
    public static func randomCar() -> Car {
        let colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange"]
        return Car(color: colors.randomElement() ?? "Red")
    }
}

@Observable
class ObservableCar<CarT>: ObservableObject where CarT: CarProtocol {
    @Published public var car: CarT
    
    public init(_ car: CarT) {
        self.car = car
    }
}

struct SwiftObservableView<CarT>: View where CarT: CarProtocol & ObservableObject {
    @StateObject var car: ObservableCar<CarT>
    
    public init(car: CarT) {
        _car = StateObject(wrappedValue: ObservableCar(car))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Modification Form")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Color", text: Binding(get: { car.car.color }, set: { car.car.color = $0 }))
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Results")) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack() {
                            Text("Color")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(car.car.color)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Actions")) {
                    Button("Random Car") {
                        self.car = ObservableCar(Car.randomCar() as! CarT)
                    }
                    Button("Assign from Objective-C") {
                        self.car.car.changeColor()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Car Data (Swift)")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftObservableView(car: Car(color: "Green"))
}

